# Echo different form on main.php page without loading whole page php

Tags: php

On my site `main.php` page's sidebar (shown on pic) have some feature for member only. Each feature is in different pages (form1.php, form2.php, etc...)

[image]

I want to know :

1. How can I call each form on `main.php`. When I click on "inbox", it should call `form1`, and when I click on "company profile" it should call `form9`.
2. Is this possible to do without loading the whole `main.php` file? If so, how?

If number 2 is too complicated, then please just help me with number 1, as that is my most important point.

Comment: Have a look [at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it this way

let us say you want to display the form on this div

```
    <div id="display">
        <!-- load it here-->
    </div>

    <!-- example this are your menus
        when you click the inbox link it will call the inbox function
        -->
    <a href="javascript:inbox()">Inbox</a>
    <a href="javascript:outbox()">Outbox</a>

    <script>
    function inbox() {
        $("#display").load("form1.php");
    }

    function outbox() {
        $("#display").load("form2.php");
    }
    </script>
```

you need to include jquery for this

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this you can use two things for that
1- If the form have database things to show use ajax with jquery

2- If it's static content you can use bootstrap tab and showing what you want